# Idiomatic way to get key from a one-item Python dict not knowing this key (but knowing the dict has only one item)?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of one-item dicts (parsed from JSON) that looks like this:

```
lst = [
{"key_0": "value_0"},
{"key_1": "value_1"},
{"key_2": "value_2"},
...
{"key_n": "value_n"}
]
```

what would be the most elegant way to retrieve a key from the list's n-element not knowing this key?

I came up with:

```
[*lst[n].keys()][0]
```

but it looks somewhat ugly to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an iterator from the dict and use the `next` function to obtain the first item:

```
next(iter(lst[n]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert direct keys to `list` and then get first item

```py
>>> n = 0
>>> list(lst[n])[0]
'key_0'
```